# Powershell to present 'Net View' data

Tags: powershell

happy Easter!

I am trying to write a script in Powershell that takes a list of hosts from a txt (or csv) and then for each does a "net view /all" on it, returning the presented shares in a csv.
I got something working but I need a column to show the host its looking at for each row otherwise I cant map them back.
Attempt 1 returns the data and the host but looks VERY messy and is proving difficult to dissect in Excel:

```
$InputFile = 'M:\Sources\Temp\net_view_list.txt'
$addresses = get-content $InputFile

foreach($address in $addresses) {

$sharedFolders = (NET.EXE VIEW $address /all) 

    foreach ($item in $sharedfolders)
    {
        $str_list = $address + "|" + $item 
        $obj_list = $str_list | select-object @{Name='Name';Expression={$_}}
        $obj_list | export-csv -append M:\sources\temp\netview.csv -notype
    }
}
```

Attempt 2 works better but cant get the hostname listed, plus the comments seem to appear in the "Used as" section (only using for one host to test the theory (didnt work!)):

```
$command = net view hostname #/all

$netview = $command -split '\n'

$comp = $netview[0].trim().split()[-1] 
 
$result = $netview -match '\w' | foreach { 
 
    convertfrom-string $_.trim() -delim '\s{2,}' -propertynames 'Share','Type', 'Used as', 'Comment'
    }

$result[0] = $null

$result | format-table 'Share', 'Type', 'Used as', 'Comment' -hidetableheaders
```

Also neither of these accounts for issues where the host either isn't accessible or has 0 shares.
I have literally spent all day on these - grateful for any guidance!

Comment: Is there any specific reason you aren't using the [SMBShare](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/smbshare/?view=windowsserver2019-ps) powershell module?

Comment: Hi Doug - I dont have permissions to setup a CIM session or query WMI.

Answer (score 0):

I will provide the way to get what you want in the your 1st example. The main reason it is not appearing like you are expecting it to is because you are not dealing with a PowerShell object. You are getting the raw output from an external command. What you need to do is take the data and create a PS Custom object then you can use it as you will. Below is the code that you should add after you have the $SharedFolder populated heavily commented to explain what each part is for.

```
# Create Array to hold PSCustom Object and variable to tell when the DO loop is done
$share_list = @()
$completed = $false

# Loop through each line in the output 
for($x=0;$x -lt $sharedFolders.count;$x++){
    $next_line = $x + 1
    # If the line is a bunch of - then we know the next line contains the 1st share name.
    if($sharedFolders[$x] -like "*-------*"){
        # Here we will loop until we find the end of the list of shares
        do {
            # Take the line and split it in to an array. Note when you 
            # use -split vs variable.split allows you to use regular
            # expressions. the '\s+' will consider x number of spaces as one
            # the single quotes are important when using regex. Double 
            # quotes use variable expansion. Single quotes don't

            $content = $sharedFolders[$next_line] -split '\s+'
            $share_name = $content[0].Trim()

            # Create a PS Custom Object. This is a bit over kill for one item
            # but shows you how to create a custom Object. Note the Object last 
            # just one loop thus you create a new one each go round then add it to 
            # an Array before the loop starts over.
            $custom_object = new-object PSObject
            $custom_object | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -name 'Share Name' -Value $share_name

            # Add the Custom Object to the Array
            $share_list += $custom_object

            # This exits the Do loop by setting $completed to true
            if($sharedFolders[$next_line] -like "*command completed*"){
                $completed = $true
            }

            # Set to the next line 
            $next_line++
        } until ($completed)
    }
}
$share_list
```

Comment: Many thanks for this - it has helped explain some of my misunderstandings.
Unfortunately the output to this only gives the shares in a list, it does not include all of the other headers returned i.e. 'Type', 'Used as' or 'Comment'. If Type is always disk then that can be omitted I guess, Used as seems to be always blank (as far as I can see) but I do see entries in the comments that I need to pull out.
Also the main ask was to include the host name in the data so when I run this against a list of hosts I can see which line item (sharename, type, comment line) came from which host.

Comment: @LiamDocherty to be honest its been along time since I used net view, but I seem to recall the only useful bit of info I ever got was the list of shares on the target server. The other three fields never, at least for me, gave anything useful. The comments could be but not for automation at least. ANy way I am glad it helped your understanding some. Also keep in mind this is but one way, in PowerShell there is always more than one way to get to where you are going.